# iPhone webapp breaks when adding to home screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, ios, mobile

I'm in the middle of creating an webapp for iPhone and I have some issues with. I want to implement an auto complete to a search form I have. Everything seems to be working well, both on desktop and web browsers, including iPhone's mobile Safari (when the user start typing, a suggested result is being shown).

The issue is when I add the app to the home screen ("Add To Home Screen" in Safari). The apps is added but when I try using the search box, there are no suggestions like in the browser. The event I capture is jQuery's keyup.

Any idea how to fix this behavior?

- Shai

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems to work after deleting it, clearing history and adding it again.